# Check if a Facebook user is currently live streaming?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a friend who live streams on Facebook. His Facebook ID is `501026873`

I am trying to use the Facebook Live Video API to check every 10 minutes if he is live, and if he is live, embed his stream on my website. However, I have been completely unable to get the `live_videos` endpoint to work without getting permission errors.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=501026873%2Flive_videos&version=v2.7

Going to that URL, no matter what permissions I give my access token, I get the following errors:

```
{
 "error": {
  "message": "(#100) No permission to perform current operation.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "DT8l6kIWhtn"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user's `live_videos` endpoint is available only to an access token **for that user** with the `user_videos` extended permission. You won't be able to use your own access token to access the endpoint.

Comment: So then there is no way to check if a user is currently live streaming?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod As far as I'm aware, only if that user has connected to your app and you have an access token as a result.